# html form methode=post action=URL

Tags: html, forms

i make a form and my submit button does not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">


        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/?lang=en&p=send" role="form">

          <div class="messages"></div>

          <div class="controls">
            <!--  Name -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                  <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--  End Name -->
            <!--  SUBJECT -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_subject">Subject *</label>
                  <input id="form_subject" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Subject *" required="required" data-error="Subject is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--  END SUBJECT -->
            <!--  Message -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                  <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--  End Message -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

when i put the relative address from my send file in the action part than it works.
is it possible on my way?
i include the content part via php in my index.php. I try to open the send.php in my index.php

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the whole HTML and not just the form tag

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. Do you want it to display the information when a user has filled the form or do you want it to send it to your email?

Comment: i want to send the information via email its a formmailer.
it works all fine when i set action="php/en/send.php" thats the adress from the send file.
but i want that the send.php is include in my index.php (I do it via $_GET['lang'] and $_GET['p'] this works fine but not with the form....

Comment: Okay, but you don't say that it should be send to an email.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right you want to handle the action of the form on the same page. So you have to set the action to:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

And in the PHP part you have to check if the form was submitted. So something like:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['form_message'])){ //check if form was submitted

}    
?>
```